# javascript variable undefined (out of scope)

Tags: javascript

I have a odd problem with reference to a variable. My setup is following:

```
var pattern = {/* some object with patterns */};

var view = (new function() {

    this.create_single = function(response) {
        pattern.block // this returns pattern object correctly
    };

    this.create_multi = function(response) {
        pattern.multi_block // this returns pattern as undefined
    };

}());

var data = (new function() {

    this.acquisition = function(response) {
        view.create_single(response);
        view.create_multi(response);
    };

}());
```

So in the `create_multi` method pattern variable returns `undefined` and i don't have any clue why its happening. In Adobe Dreamweaver (which i am using to write code) i have a line error that says `'pattern' used out of scope`. Can anyone help me understand what is happening ?

Thank You for all the help ;)

Comment: is there a property `multi_block` inside the pattern object ?

Comment: yes it is defined there, the problem is with `pattern` itself `undefined` not `multi_block` property inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is okay but your 'view' method's returning nothing. It is working fine with following scenario:

```
var pattern = {
    block: 1,
    multi_block: 2
};

var view = (new function() {

    this.create_single = function(response) {
        return pattern.block // this returns pattern object correctly
    };

    this.create_multi = function(response) {
        return pattern.multi_block // this returns pattern as undefined
    };


}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one without parameter passing

```js
var pattern = {multi_block:"mblock", block:"block" };

var view = ( function() { 
   var create_single = function(response) {
      return pattern.block // this returns pattern object   correctly
   };
   
   var create_multi = function(response) {
    return  pattern.multi_block // this returns pattern as undefined
   };
   return create_single;
}());

console.log(view);
```

Comment: well this obviously will work but it was not the idea to pass entire object as parameter to a function, it should be available globally without need of passing. I am trying to debug more complex problem here.

Comment: i'm thinking the problem is the keyword `new`, which might be creating a new object stack for which local variables of the previous stack are invisible

Comment: if you read the code again, `pattern` is available for use in the `create_single` method, so why would it be unavailable for `create_multi` ? thats crazy

Comment: from your code, for the variable `view` you're assigning the return value of a function that returns nothing. So I'm surprised that `view.create_single(response);` worked to begin with

Comment: Currently you altered my code entirely, it was used with keyword `new` because it is static class, that needs to be accessed from outside, it cannot stand like this, but i solved a problem, it was a structure problem i will print answer in few min.